# git: import changes from non git repository

Tags: git, ftp, merge

Scenario:

- Local git repo, default master branch
- FTP server with content of the repo (non git), synchronized daily with the local repo, master branch

Workflow:

- user1 is working on local git repo (git add, working directory clean)
- user2 (non git user) changed files directly on the FTP server

How can I import all files changed on FTP to the local git repo and see what has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds a bit nightmarish. I assume it is no option to have a git repository on the FTP server. In that case I would create a separate branch in my work repository:

```
git checkout -b ftp
```

copy the ftp stuff over and commit it to the branch:

```
git commit -a
```

then go back to the master:

```
git checkout master
```

and do the normal merge, diff, cherry-pick from the FTP branch. You might want to delete the FTP directory after merging is done.

Comment: I'm interested how would you detect deleted files from the ftp? I.e. you have the file in your git repository but in future it gets deleted from the ftp. How would you detect those files?