# Import changes from ftp to git

Tags: git, ftp, merge

I'm working on a project with a couple of developers. Currently all of them store their work on an ftp server and they aren't using any VCS. Because of that, I have create my own local git repository so I could have a history of the changes.

The way I'm merging everything is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943235/393805) answer. I have a branch for the ftp code, then I would download the latest code from the ftp, afterwords I would commit and merge. My only problem is that it's becoming a mess - I can't track which files are deleted from the ftp. I can only see the new files and the changed ones.

Is there another beter solution?

Comment: You mean besides not working with developers who refuse to use a VCS for some mysterious reason?

Comment: Whilst I salute your dedication in trying to mirror the FTP directory, I don't think you're solving the fundamental issue here, which is a lack of VCS project-wide

Comment: Yeah, it's odd they don't want to use VCS but that's the situation in the moment. :(

Comment: I don't see why you can't just create a repo on the FTP. Who cares if you are the only one committing to it?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle never thought about that. How would I then pull from it?

Comment: I (on ubuntu) would mount the ftp to a local folder and use it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a fresh working directory to fetch each new copy, so that it wouldn't have any files that had been removed. Then combine this with using `git add -A` to stage files for removal and use of the `$GIT_DIR` environment variable to specify where the git repository to use is located.

```
git checkout ftp
mkdir /tmp/ftp
cd /tmp/ftp
# Get fresh copy of code from ftp server
GIT_DIR=~-/.git git add -A
GIT_DIR=~-/.git git commit
cd ~-
git reset --hard
```

Comment: This probably is the best solution so far. Thanks! :)

Comment: Nice solution. Do not forget to reset GIT_DIR to it's initial value?

Comment: @twicejr With the way that GIT_DIR is set here, it only affects the command after the setting on the same line. It is never changed for the current session. This is why the same setting is used twice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a better solution. These other 'couple of developers' need to learn to use version control.

Whether it be Git, Mercurial, Bazaar, Subversion, or any of the paid vcs products (Perforce, etc.), there is no excuse for not using version control for any project.

There is even free, private hosting available for any of the above technologies.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you, but in this case I can't make them understand the value of vcs and there are deadlines. So I need a dirty workaround. Thanks :)

Comment: Ick, that is a sticky situation to be in. I do not envy you, best of luck though!